# How to configure eclipse cdt to work with LLVM 3.6?

Tags: eclipse, llvm, eclipse-cdt, clang++

I want to know to configure eclipse cdt to work with LLVM 3.6 instead of GCC ?

I tried llvm4eclipsecdt plugin but it seem doesn't work with LLVM version higher than 3.2 .

I'm using Windows , LLVM 3.6 (with MinGW) .

**Edit :**
when I tried llvm4eclipsecdt it cause an error because `llvm-ld` is not exists !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed CDT.
For using llvm just use "New project" -> "llvm with clang"

Comment: Unfortunately, it works CDT v8.5 but not in v8.6 ,it doesn't appear at all,  I don't know why !!